# vue-multiselect styles working in dev but not in prod

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-multiselect

I have added `<style src="vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">` to my vue component, its styles working when running `npm run dev` but not when running `npm run prod`. How to fix that?

```
<template>
    <multi-select :id="id" v-model="value" :options="options" :multiple="multiple" :max="max"></multi-select>
</template>

<script>
    import multiSelect from 'vue-multiselect';
    export default {
        name: "my-multi-select",
        components: { multiSelect },
    }
</script>

<style src="vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"></style>
```

Comment: did you try importing globally in main.js?

Comment: Yes, same result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you using a relative path. What you need is to add a ref to your `src` folder, to tell `vue-cli`, that you want to include it in your production build.

```
<style>
  @import './assets/styles/vue-multiselect.min.css';
</style>
```

The `@` refers your src path. Where you store it or what you call your folders is up to you.

---

**EDIT:** Another approach could be to reinstall the package with this command:

```
npm install vue-multiselect@next --save
```

Or just import it like you do with the component:

```
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'
import 'vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css'
```

---

**EDIT 2:** `vue.config.js`, create this file in your `root`. The content should be:

```
module.exports = {
        publicPath: './'
    };
```

Comment: I had done this too but didn't work. In the `vue-multiselect` documentation, it says it should be like the one I have set. I'm using PHPStorm, so when there is a path like that, it will show it in the suggestion popup. So I'm sure that it's the correct path.

Comment: @kodfire Are you using `.env` files?

Comment: Yes, is the problem originated from `.env` file? In the `.env` file I just have the variables for my back-end. @Fabalance

Comment: @kodfire Only, if you have set up different paths and use them. Another problem could be in the webpack config.

Comment: my webpack:            `const mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('laravel-mix-purgecss');
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/app.css')
    .webpackConfig({
        plugins: [],
        output: {chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js'}
    })
    .purgeCss({
        whitelistPatterns: [/multiselect/, /modal/]
    });`

Comment: @kodfire Added two new approaches, maybe one or both will work.

Comment: As I said it is working when running `npm run dev`, so it is importing properly in dev mode but not in prod mode. I had tested those two new approaches, same result.

Comment: @kodfire Yes, I understand that. The structure of your app is changing during the build of your production by `npm`.  The path to your css file is relative without trailing slash and that could cause problems. Please try the approach in my second edit.

Comment: I found it :)) instead of `whitelistPatterns: [/multiselect/, /modal/]` In newer version, I should have used `safelist: [/multiselect/, /modal/]`. This will exclude these styles in order not to be purged.

Comment: @kodfire Nice. Hope I could help you a little, even if I didn't solve your problem .